# mongo group by with datetime string

Tags: mongodb

I have the following data:

```
"request_time" : "Fri Mar 25 2011 17:14:53 GMT-0400 (EDT)"
```

With the following query

```
db.production.group({key:{"request_time.d": true},cond:{"action":"forward"},initial:{sum:0},reduce:function(doc,prev) {prev.sum += 1}})
```

For some reason I'm getting null in reply.  It's not distinguishing the ".d" notation which I've taken from the MongoDB Docs.  Can anyone tell me why?

This is tested out in the mongo shell on Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 0):

your "request_time" key just have a *string* as value.

If you are referring to mongoDB docs example

`{ domain: "www.mongodb.org"
, invoked_at: {d:"2009-11-03", t:"17:14:05"}
, response_time: 0.05
, http_action: "GET /display/DOCS/Aggregation"
}`

and

`db.test.group(
   { cond: {"invoked_at.d": {$gte: "2009-11", $lt: "2009-12"}}
....`

then please note that in the above code "invoked_at" have map as value which in turn have two fields - d and t.

Comment: I didn't realize that.  How in that case does one do a group by with a string data type ?